# Is there a better way of accessing and storing only required class properties

Tags: php, class, object, properties, mysqli

If I want to get a customer's email address from a database, the following is bad, because $row will contain an element for every single field in the `customer` table:

```
$result = mysqli_query ('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE custid = 1');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This is considered better, because $row will contain a single element for the email address, which is all we need:

```
$result = mysqli_query ('SELECT email FROM customer WHERE custid = 1');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I am trying to apply the same logic to objects.  If a "customer" object has say 50 properties/fields, is it common to populate all 50 properties when you only need to access one?

Below is a basic example of a customer class and object which is resource hungry if all we want to do is get a customer's email address, and not all their other details (in this example a "customer" object has 5 properties but in reality there could be many more):

```
class Customer {

    private $custid;
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;
    private $dateadded;

    public function getCustomer ($id) {
        $result = mysql_queryi ('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE custid = ' . $id);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            if (isset ($this->$key)) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

$customer = new Customer ();
$customer->getCustomer (1); // All I wanted is the email address, but now I have everything :-(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a second argument to your `getCustomer` function that accepts an array of fields to query

```
public function getCustomer ($id, $fields=array('*')) {
    $fields = implode(',', $fields);
    $result = mysql_queryi("SELECT {$fields} FROM customer WHERE ...");
    // ...
```

Usage

```
// get entire customer
$customer->getCustomer(1);

// just get the email field
$customer->getCustomer(1, array('email'));

// get full name
$customer->getCustomer(1, array('firstname', 'lastname'));
```

---

#### Bonus:

I'd recommend storing your fields a little differently in your model

```
class Customer
    private $_data;

    public function getCustomer($id, $fields=array('*')) {
        // ...
    }

    // PHP magic set method
    // calling $this->foo = 'bar' results in $this->_data['foo'] = 'bar'
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        return $this->_data[$key] = $value;
    }

    // PHP magic get method
    // calling $this->foo results in $this->_data['foo']
    public function __get($key) {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->_data)
            ? $this->_data[$key]
            : null
        ;
    }
}
```

This way you can get rid of all the statically defined instance variables; e.g., `private $custid;`, `private $firstname;`, `private ...`

Instead, all fields will be stored in `$this->_data` private associative array.

What's sweet about this is you don't even have to change the way your `getCustomer` function is written.

[Learn more about PHP magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a get Email address method:

```
public function getCustomerEmail ($id) {
    $result = mysql_queryi ('SELECT email FROM customer WHERE custid = ' . (int)$id);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if (isset ($this->$key)) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:** don't forget to sanitize your variables before using them in a query

Comment: Solid PS, that is a nightmare waiting to happen haha

Comment: Yes - although I would prefer to cast it to (int) outside of the function rather than inside.  But in the case of strings you'd certainly want to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

First...
You really should seperate the logic for fetching customer objects from the actuall object... I would suggest looking at the repository/facade patterns for examples. 
*Eg. CustomerCollectionInstance->getCustomer($id) returns a Customer Entity.*

Your example is extremely simple so the difference from pulling just the e-mail and all thoes fields should be insignificant. If your objects are massively, say a customer who could have 500 orders. The orders should be separated into there own objects, and when the entity object is assembled thoes heavy objects should not be loaded but have proxy objects in their place that when accessed then query the db for that data.

eg.

- You call getCustomer on the CustomerCollection...
- CustomerCollection returns a CustomerEntity with basic data loaded and the customerOrders is set with a CustomerOrderCollectionProxy object..
- You call CustomerEntity->getOrders() which return the CustomerOrderCollectionProxy object
- Once you make a call to the CustomerOrderCollectionProxy it will first check if it has loaded the required data from the DB... if not it will then assemble a real CustomerOrderCollection and delegate all calls to that object that now has the date you need.

See the proxy pattern for an example.